# Cound I limit an API resource to the count that I want?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I am using the AWS API gateway for months. I just need a feature now. **I have to limit an API resource to the count that I want.** Are there any possibilities to do that? I need to restrict the user when they reached a particular count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Api Gateway has a feature called Usage Plans and is used to limit the numbers of requests over time, also are used to limit the use of the API for economic reasons. According to documentation:

> After you create, test, and deploy your APIs, you can use API Gateway usage plans to make them available as product offerings for your customers. You can configure usage plans and API keys to allow customers to access selected APIs at agreed-upon request rates and quotas that meet their business requirements and budget constraints. If desired, you can set default method-level throttling limits for an API or set throttling limits for individual API methods.

More information:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html